# How would I update the query string with ?m=11&y=2014 every time I clicked on next button?

Tags: php, jquery

--header--

```
<div class="table-header-wrapper">
                <div class="prev"></div>
                <div class="year"><?php echo $current_year; ?></div>
                <div class="next"></div>
            </div>
```

--php tabbed month code--

```
<?php
    for ($monthNum = 1; $monthNum <= 12; $monthNum++) :
        $month = date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $monthNum, 1, $current_year)); // month in 3 letter format e.g. Jan
        $current_monthNum = date('n'); // current month in number
        ?>
        <div class="<?php echo strtolower($month); ?> month" data-month="<?php echo $monthNum; ?>">
            <a href="<?php echo home_url('admin-events-list') . '/?' . addQuery(array('m' => $monthNum, 'y' => $current_year)); ?>" class="<?php echo ( $current_monthNum == $monthNum ? 'current' : '' ); ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></a>
        </div>
        <?php
    endfor;
?>
```

=== html structure ===

< 2014 >

[jan] [feb] [mar] [apr]...etc

?m=11&y=2014
y variable increment on next button clicked.

Button on the --header-- increases/decreases by 1 and also updates the query string in the month tab href e.g domain.com/?m=11&y=2014 if clicked next domain.com/?m=11&y=2015. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: whre is month href here ?

Comment: Thanks for asking @CodingAnt, the code on <a href="<?php php code ?>" generates a url with query string url/?m=11&y=2014 and I want to increment the variable y by 1 every time I clicked the next button.

Comment: Would doing that with javascript be an option? There is n awesome time-framework called moment.js, which easily can add/subtract days, hours etc. to given dates. From the result, you could build the href dynamically.

Comment: @Daniel need this to work on php & jquery, I'll explain more the scenario on this part '< 2014 >' arrows are next and previous buttons, increments/decrements the year. And on this part [jan][feb][mar]... are tabs generated through php date() and this is clickable in which each tab is a representation of events created based on the year and month would be displayed.

Comment: I got the scenario. My question essentially was: are you able to add additional JS-frameworks? If yes, you could increment easily with moment: moment("2014", "YYYY").add("years", 1).format("YYYY"), where "2014" could also get it's value from the div, if it had an id or something like that. Then with JS (or jQuery) you could dynamically create link, or do a window.location with the generated URI. This whole logic would be triggerd via onlick on the clickable tabs.

Comment: I didn't use any additional JS-frameworks. Trying to solve this through plain jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will simply update the innerHTML of the year, but you can change the functionality however you want:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="prev" onclick="$('#year').html(parseInt($('#year').html())-1);$('.month').each(function(e, obj){obj.href=obj.href.substr(0,obj.href.length-4)+$('#year').html()})">PREVIOUS</div>
<div class="year" id="year">2014</div>
<div class="next" onclick="$('#year').html(parseInt($('#year').html())+1);$('.month').each(function(e, obj){obj.href=obj.href.substr(0,obj.href.length-4)+$('#year').html()})">NEXT</div>
<div id="months"><a class="month" href="domain.com/?m=09&y=2014">sep</a>&nbsp;<a class="month" href="domain.com/?m=10&y=2014">oct</a>&nbsp;<a class="month" href="domain.com/?m=11&y=2014">nov</a>&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, I already done this part the only lacking is the [jan][feb][mar].. which is a link with href need to update the y variable depends on the current #year which is incremented by 1 every click on next button.

Comment: I've updated the code-snippet. If that's not what you want, then please  rephrase your question.